# How to design a auto-touch attachment for capacitance screen?

Tags: capacitance, touchscreen, touch-panel

I’m thinking about developing an attachment which is able to “touch” the capacitance touch screen just like the human fingers do, it might be a membrane layer can be sticked to the capacitance touch screen, when sending different signals to it, it will “touch” at specified coordinates of the screen like human fingers do. Meanwhile, the layer should be transparent.
Does anyone have idea? Very appreciate it.

Comment: Why don't you interface to the existing touch screen electronics instead?

Comment: @Andyaka Because this ware should be used as an attachment, in this scene, it won’t be able to access the electronics of the touch screen.

Comment: How will you remove it once stuck in place?

Comment: @Andyaka Just like cellphone screen protector (membrane )